# Verbs with separable prefixes in colloquial speech

Tags: colloquial, separable-verb

Are separable prefixes sometimes not separated from verbs in colloquial speech by native German speakers, when grammar actually calls for such a separation?

Example:

> Die Blumen sehen sehr schön aus.

This is a grammatically correct sentence. But in colloquial speech would native German speakers sometimes say

> Die Blumen aussehen sehr schön?

Comment: That sounds very strange. Native german speakers would never say that.

Comment: @awita should be an answer

Comment: One source of  your question might be that there are verbs that *look like* they were separable, but *aren't*. We say "Hans frühstückte heute morgen" and not "Hans stückte heute morgen früh"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the *Verbklammer* is not an optional nicety that people tend to omit in casual speech. It really is an essential, deeply ingrained part of learning to speak native German. Even though this seems quite weird to native speakers of English, it seems very "normal" to us, and hearing it mishandled sounds very weird to us. (Even though there is a strong tendency of modern German to evolve towards phenomena as they are in English, so far this hasn't affected basic clause syntax.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a native speaker and I have to say that your first sentence correct, the second one is not. Second one is false and is never used by Germans. Hope it helps.